# Verizon email to text being cut off early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sms, mandrill

I am writing a `Ruby on Rails` app using `Mandrill` to [send email to text.](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/4318204)

My texts are working fine for AT&T, T-Mobile, and Sprint. But my texts to Verizon are being cut off. I've read that Verizon has a character limit of 160 characters, but my texts are being cut off earlier than that, around 80 characters.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

I am sending just plain text emails.

**Edit - Code per request**

**Mailer:**

```
class Texter < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "texts@domain.com"

 def test(number, content)
    @content = content
    mail(:to => number)
 end
end
```

**View (test.text.erb)**

```
<%= @content %>
```

Comment: Show us your stripped code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan there isnt really much code to show, a basic rails mailer that sends an email

Comment: @theTinMan put it up either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the ##########@vtext.com address for Verizon users, use the alternate ##########@vzwpix.com which allows for Verizon customers to receive longer MMS messages or messages that contain pictures and video.

I was finding messages sent to the vtext.com address were being truncated at 150 characters (actual truncation appears to vary depending on the number of characters in the email address or if the message contains a subject line, etc.) Additional messages were not automatically generated with the remainder of the original message, they were simply truncated.

Sending to the vzwpix.com address I was able to receive the full length of the message, far exceeding a 150-160 character limit.

Answer (score 4):

The character limitation is actually caused simply by the fact that the SMS protocol defines a maximum payload size of `1120` bits.

In matter of characters, length varies according to encoding.

- 7-bit = 160 characters
- 8-bit = 140 characters
- 16-bit = 70 characters

Additionally some providers include `From` and/or `Subject` fields in the message content which additionally decreases the number of available space you can use for your message.

Comment: Why isnt it happening to the other carriers then? Just verizon.

Comment: @Deekor Probably the API they use issues UTF-8. So you already have ≈ 70 characters.

Comment: I just tried it though gmail to verizon and there was no cut off.

Comment: @Deekor Well for some reason you are sending UTF-8 or other multi-byte encoding. I can't know where it comes from, but debug and trace it and  you'll find where it comes from.

Comment: So you think I should be using UTF-7? If I'm getting through around 90 characters wouldn't that mean its using 16-bit?

Comment: When sending it says `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` so I'm already using 7bit it would seem.

Comment: Again.. This is usually the issue, but it might not be on your side. If you are doing everything correctly and it work everywhere else but there, file a report. Send them the bug or call Technical Support. P.S. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You state that the emails to SMS work for other providers such as AT&T, T-Mobile and Sprint. Your email content is probably ok, but to verify that hypothesis, try sending an email manually to the Verizon email-to-sms gateway.

From there you'll either find out it's the content of your email or the gateway itself is the problem.  Hopefully you'll get a response from the gateway with some sort of diagnostic, if there is a problem.

Another option I'd recommend is the **[sms-fu gem](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu)** [1].  As a bonus, it supports more providers than the 4 you mentioned.

Good luck!

[1] https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I'll give them a shot.

Comment: Tried it though gmail to verizon and there was no cut off.